# Array to string conversion in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a simple question but I cannot figure it out alone.

I want the column of the table to hold the part key as `href` to another page that does something. Without the `href` it works fine.

```
echo "<table border='1' style='width:300px'>";
echo "<tr>
        <th>KEY</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>MFGR</th>
        <th>BRAND</th>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>SIZE</th>
        <th>CONTAINER</th>
        <th>RETAIL PRICE</th>
        <th>COMMENT</th>
      </tr>";
while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    //The following line gives me "Notice: Array to string conversion":
    echo "<td><a href='part.php'?item_n= ".$array[0]."&key= ".$nkey."> ".$array[0]. "</a></td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[1]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[2]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[3]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[4]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[5]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[6]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[7]. "</td>";
    echo "<td> ".$array[8]. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The line that gives me trouble is the one with the `href` as I mentioned.

Comment: Define "gives me trouble"

Comment: Awfull way of doing an HTML array, are you aware of templating ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from `$nKey` not being defined anywhere, you have problems on this line:

```
echo "<td><a href='part.php'?item_n= ".$array[0]."&key= ".$nkey."> ".$array[0]. "</a></td>";
//                         ^
```

That's not where the `href` ends. You need to move this to where it actually ends:

```
echo "<td><a href='part.php?item_n= ".$array[0]."&key= ".$nkey."'> ".$array[0]. "</a></td>";
//                                                              ^
```

**Edit**:

Your real problem is that `$nkey` is an array, and not a string as you're expecting. Since this variable has been left out of the posted script it's hard to give any further suggestions until it's seen.

Comment: he has posted a part of his code how come you're sure he has not declared `$nKey` at any part of his code?

Comment: @Fallen I am not, but it *might* be an issue. Any example posted is supposed to be a full example, which means that `$nkey` should have been included in the original script. If he said that "this line gets an error" instead of "the line that gives me trouble" we'd know for sure. :-)

Comment: I defined it before this part of code. Anyway, that change didn't help me. I still get " Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: @shnorkel What does `print_r($nkey)` output? It's an array, right?

Comment: BINGO! I was wrong to assume that if the query result had one column and one row it would return a single value. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='part.php'?item_n= ".$array[0]."&key= ".$nkey."> ".$array[0]. "</a>
                 ^
```

This single quote is misplaced, place it after the whole address,

```
<a href='part.php?item_n= ".$array[0]."&key= ".$nkey."'> ".$array[0]. "</a>
                                                      ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "<td><a href='part.php?item_n=".$array[0]."&key=".$nkey."'>".$array[0]. "</a></td>";
```

OR

```
echo "<td><a href='part.php?item_n=$array[0]&key=$nkey'>".$array[0]. "</a></td>";
```